# Can't even get a UITableView to show

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode5

I'm starting to learn to program and I'm already getting a really annoying problem. When I follow, step by step, the Apple Developer guide "Start Developing iOS Apps Today" and I add a UITableViewController (even if it's the only view controller in the project) and I set it as the initial ViewController, I run the app to check if it works and I can't get the table view to show, all I see is a blank static background.

It doesn't matter what kind of cell I use, the table view doesn't appear.

What am I doing wrong?

Xcode 5.1, target: iOS 7.1

Comment: blank? do you at least see the lines?

Comment: Nop, that's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to get `UItableView` to show

- Drag a `UITableViewController` to the storyboard
- Give your prototype cell an `Identifier` (e.g "cell")
- Create a Objective-C class file that inherits from the `UITableViewController` Class.
- Assign that class to the `ViewController` you dragged
- Return at least one `section`
- Return at least one `row` per `section`
- Set a text for the cell in `cellAtRowIndex`

---

I created a <kbd>**[DEMO PROJECT](https://mega.co.nz/#!nYglgR6b!XS0owfX3zDcD_i_b5H0wDeygylbHJzRfwT62KbtqkzY)**</kbd> for you, see how I did things over there.

Comment: I still can't get it to work. I drag a UITableViewController to the storyboard, then I set the cell style to "Basic" and I modify the label to "First cell" and set the Identifier to "Cell 1". Then I use Cmd+N and in the pop-up menu I select "Objective-C class" I call the class "MainTableViewController", and I change the "subclass of" to "UITableViewController" and I create it. Back in the storyboard, I select the UITableViewController and set "Custom Class" to "MainTableViewController". In the MainTableViewController.m I set return to 1 in both sections and rows and then I run it -> blank

Comment: This is weird. If I run your project, it works. Even if I delete the ViewController.h and .m and add a different TableView on the storyboard, it shows at least the lines instead of a blank page. If I create the same project, with the exact same code, names and everything, all I get is a black screen (not even white) What could be the problem?

Comment: If you use a `UIViewController` instead of a `UITableViewController` you will need to hook everything up, such as delegates, datasource, and outlet reference, but this is all built-in when using a `UITableViewController`

Answer (score 0):

You can't show a blank table, you need content to show to be able to see your table.